# Remove rows/columns from MatrixStore in OjAlgo

Tags: ojalgo

Is there any convenient and efficient way to remove rows (or columns) from `SparseMatrix` in ojAlgo? I was trying to retrieve `RowView` from my matrix and then copy rows that should remain element by element to new matrix but this is not very efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the same thing but using the `ElementView2D` obtained from the `nonzeros()` method would be much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this. Is it possible to select rows to be copied by using e.g. ElementSupplier or RowsSupplier interfaces and then supplyTo method with destination object as parameter?

Comment: The problem with RowView and ColumnView is that they essentially assume the underlying data structure is dense (efficient random access). RowsSupplier or ColumnsSupplier could be alternatives for you. Do you need to be able to remove both rows and columns?

Comment: I need to remove both but not simultaneously. I think the problem is that my sparse matrix has 9M non-zero elements. Even creating by looping over them and using `set` from `SparseStore` takes around 5 minutes.

Comment: ojAlgo currently doesn't have a mechanism to do efficient bulk inserts to sparse matrices (that could be useful when doing a copy). A PR to do that would be appreciated. Do you really need to copy that matrix? Would like to point out that creating a custom matrix implementation in ojAlgo is really simple: https://github.com/optimatika/ojAlgo/wiki/Create-Custom-MatrixStore Create your own that does precisely what you need, and optimise the operations that matter to you.